# Key Bindings Fire Multiple Times when Holding Key

Tags: java, swing

I'm following [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) guide to get key binding to work in my application.  So far, the key bindings fire successfully, when I press a key.  What I expect to happen is when I bind one action to a key pressed event and another action to a key released event, it will fire the first action when the key is pressed down and the second action when the key is released.  What actually happens when I hold down a key is both actions get called multiple times.  What can I do to achieve my desired behavior?

Here's how I'm implementing the key bindings:

```
component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed UP"), "pressedUP");
component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released UP"), "releasedUP");

Action pressedUpAction = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Pressed UP");
    }           
};

Action releasedUpAction = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Released UP");
    }           
};

component.getActionMap().put("pressedUP", pressedUpAction);
component.getActionMap().put("releasedUP", releasedUpAction);
```

When I run the program, the output I actually get when I hold down the up key is `Pressed UP`, a slight pause, and then multiple `Pressed UP` values.  When I release the up key, I get a `Released UP` message.  The entire output looks like this:

```
Pressed UP
Pressed UP
Pressed UP
Pressed UP
Pressed UP
Pressed UP
Pressed UP
Released UP
```

The really weird thing is if I replace UP with a keyboard letter key, such as `P`, everything works as I expect it to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- use `Boolean` value inside [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) when once times fired events then change `Boolean`  from `false` to `true` or vice versa
- I'm sorry nobody knows how did you implemented [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: an Action already _has_ a boolean which is appropriate to use here: it's called _enabled_ :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry when I first typed this.  I'll post a SSCCE right now.

Comment: I see what you mean by a boolean variable now.  I was misunderstanding how keyboard events work.  Thanks for the help.